# Finding longest repeating sequence in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find the longest repeating sequence in a list of lists.

```
list = 
  {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6},{ 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 2, 9}, 
   {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}};
```

Expected Output

> ```
> {{ 1, 2, 3}},{{ 4, 5, 6} ,{5, 6, 7},{7, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}
> ```

Here `{ 4, 5, 6}` is the repeating element and longest sequence is being displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Start by taking time to [**read the FAQ**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq). In general, we like to have questions with a bit more context, information, and effort, rather than "give me the code"-style questions. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself already? What have you tried? Can you give more detail about your query?

Answer (score 2):

```
d=Last@SortBy[Tally@list,Last];
{{Range@d[[2]]},list[[First@Last@Position[list,d[[1]]];;All]]}
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}}